# How to get a line from a file, but NOT line by line, using std?

Tags: c++, std

trying to read a line from a file, but dont know which line while writing code.
tried

```
function()
{
    int j;
    std::string myline;
    std::fstream m_myfile;
    myline = std::get<j>(m_myfile);
}
```

based on [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get]

```
std::get<0>(t)
```

but gives `error: the value of ‘j’ is not usable in a constant expression`

tried variations of std::get, m_myfile.get, std::getline, and m_myfile.getline

j may be 1 or 17 or 114 or something higher.

---

edit 19/12/2023
This is not a duplicate of  "How to read a line from a text file in c/c++? [duplicate] (5 answers)", because this question is not about how to read a line, but a specific line.
This is not a duplicate of "Read file line by line using ifstream in C++ (8 answers)", because is is not asking how to read line by line, but how to get a specific line, **not** line by line.

The answer is the is no way as of 19/12/2023.
"There's no one line command in c++ to skip ahead to a certain line in a text file, looping is the main solution and can be tedious but you can try and focus on shortening the loop based on the contents of your text file. – 2011cmpunk 4 hours ago"
another possible answer
"Then probably you should choose another format for data storate, not a simple text file. Maybe use database? Another option, if length of lines is limited, you can pad each line up to fixed block size which is maximum allowed length. Waste of disk space but instant access to any line number. – dimich 23 hours ago"

this question should be marked answered.

Comment: You will definitely not need std::get, that's more for template programming. Basic file IO is sequential and you will need to read line by line. If you know the exact offset in the file of your line you can use : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg

Comment: But really just get started here : [Basic FileIO](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/basic-file-io/) from learncpp.com

Answer (score 0):

`std::get<0>(t)` is meant for tuples and not text files, `t` should be a tuple data structure like the example they set in cppreference as `t`.

```
auto t = std::make_tuple(1, "Foo", 3.14);
```

If you want to read from a file and specify the line number to read from, with j as the line number, another solution could be to create a loop and read each line individually until you reach line j, then save that line.

`getline()` is better used for reading lines from a file in c++.

Comment: "If you want to read from a file and specify the line number to read from, with j as the line number" how?    "another solution could be to create a loop and read each line individually until you reach line j, then save that line." very consuming,  especially when j can be in the thousands.

Comment: I think explaining std::tuple is totally unecessary here. std::tuple is typically only to be used in template programming (since it is semantically meaningless). In all other cases declaring an explicit struct is the better option (since it cannot be confused with other tuples and will have readable members variable names)

Comment: @MichaelBridges Have you actually did that? How long did it take? How is that slow?

Comment: @Pepijn Kramer, tuple is not usable for for reading my file, I did not understand it was for tuple only.

Comment: @Passer By, no I have not looped through file. even if it only takes 0.0001 ms, it is more looping than just going to the desired line.

Comment: @MichaelBridges _"very consuming"_ – If we are talking about an arbitrary text file, where each line can have a different length, then such a file is just a sequence of bytes, some of which can be newline bytes. So, how would you imagine locating in that sequence the byte that corresponds to the beginning of, say, line number 42, if you don't want to examine all previous bytes to count the lines? Impossible. Unless you have some sort of index for that file (but again, to create such an index, you'll need to examine all bytes).

Comment: @heap underrun, if one wants the 4th line, then look find 3rd '\n', then read biytes till next '\n'

Comment: @MichaelBridges _"look find 3rd '\n'"_ – Exactly, and to find the 3rd `'\n'`, you'll need to look through the file's contents, from the beginning, to find the 1st `'\n'`, then find the 2nd `'\n'`, and so on: thus, looping. And because we don't know, for example, how many bytes after the 1st `'\n'` there is before we encounter the 2nd `'\n'`, this means we must also examine all the bytes in between (to see if these are `'\n'` or non-`'\n'`).

Comment: _"even if it only takes 0.0001 ms, it is more looping than just going to the desired line"_ that is an exceedingly incorrect mindset. Your time is limited. Our time is limited. Trying to fix what isn't a problem is wasting everyone's time. Identify the real problems and fix those instead.

Comment: @MichaelBridges Do I understand correctly that you do not want to use `getline()` in a loop because `getline()` reads the whole line into memory, whereas you'd like to only read each single byte into memory, until you encounter the desired line? In that case, you could write a function that reads single bytes in a loop and skips them. But such a solution will probably waste more time that looping with `getline()`, because file access is usually buffered by the OS, and thus it is more efficient to read by larger chunks rather than single bytes at a time.

Comment: @heap underrun, no you dont understand. if there is a getline(filename, linenumber), or similar syntex, is what I have been looking for, not for(filename, line, j++){if(j == linenumber){}}

Comment: @MichaelBridges Read entire file once and create lookup table which contains offsets for each line indexed by line number. Probably store this table to another file. Then you can read specific line by its offset in file. Of course, you'll need to re-build table every time file is changed.

Comment: @MichaelBridges • Instead of reading a line into a string, you can ignore the lines that are not of interest, and getline the line that is of interest.  Probably won't change the performance profile much.

Comment: @ dimich, :) o, file is changed a lot, a very very very lot.

Comment: @Eljay, "Instead of reading a line into a string, you can ignore the lines that are not of interest, and getline the line that is of interest." how?

Comment: Ignore one line: `m_myfile.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');`

Comment: @MichaelBridges Then probably you should choose another format for data storate, not a simple text file. Maybe use database? Another option,  if length of lines is limited, you can pad each line up to fixed block size which is maximum allowed length. Waste of disk space but instant access to any line number.

Comment: @Eljay, really dont understand how "m_myfile.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');" can be used to find a specific line.

Comment: @MichaelBridges • Let's say you want the 4th line.  You `ignore` 3 lines, then `getline` the 4th line.

Comment: @MichaelBridges There's no one line command in c++ to skip ahead to a certain line in a text file, looping is the main solution and can be tedious but you can try and focus on shortening the loop based on the contents of your text file.